# What technology is behind a deep freezer door

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, machine-design

I dont know if the title or question makes any sense but when i close my deep freezer i find it difficult to open immediately after closing until after about 2 minutes have passed. How is this done and why? It works all the same with no power source

Does it have something to do with the door seal? I dont get it

Comment: Freezer makers do this on purpose in order to perpetuate the mystery of whether or not the light goes out ;)

Comment: Well they were unsuccessful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a different scale and with different and more severe temperature variations, consider the following:
Place a few ounces/tens of milliliters of water in a plastic bottle. Heat it to boiling in a microwave oven. As soon as the water reaches the boiling point, remove it and tighten the cap.

As the water vapor, which is [less dense than dry air](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_vapor), condenses, the space in which it previously occupied is "vacated" causing a pressure reduction. In this extreme example, the plastic bottle will collapse quite dramatically.

In the case of your freezer, when the door is open, some of the cold air within will fall out, due to the increased density when compared to the ambient air. This vacancy causes humid air from outside the freezer to be pulled into the enclosure.

When the door is closed, the air is quite quickly chilled, causing water vapor to condense, reducing the pressure. Additionally, one could consider that the warmer air is less dense and when chilled, becomes more dense, also causing a pressure reduction.

This pressure reduction, combined with what you have described as a well sealing door, results in the difficulty of opening the door.

I have duplicated the collapsing bottle process and also have experienced additional force required to open my refrigerator and freezer doors.

Comment: Your plastic bottle experiment was done in our physics class some 45 years ago with a  1 gallon steel oil can - about an inch of water was brought to the boil and then the lid screwed on tight. Atmospheric pressure and time as it cooled did the rest.

Comment: @fred thanks for the detailed reply. It almost feels like a feature rather than something that just happens. My fridge dosent behave the same way

Comment: @Tony that is exactly the behavior that you described in your question

Comment: How does thjs explain why it becomes easy to open again after 2 minutes?

Comment: @DKNguyen, the seal is not perfect and the migration of outside air into the freezer compartment reduces or eliminates the pressure difference holding the door closed.

Answer (score 1):

The soft seal on your freezer door allows the door to spring up slightly after the door is closed. But only slightly, because the soft seal (with magnetic closure) prevents the entry of air into the chamber, so the door is held closed by air pressure.

The seal is not perfect, and over a couple of seconds (or minutes), the air pressure equalizes, allowing the door to open easily again.

Before the invention of soft magnetic seals, freezer doors did not 'stick' when closed, and used heavy clamps to keep the door sealed.